If L+ is a sublanguage of L, and {A} is a set of axioms and transformation rules used to create S and S+, is every theorem of S+ a theorem of S?
I am not sure whether this holds universally or not. On one hand, since L+ is a sublanguage of L, since the axioms and inference rules are the same for S and S+, it seems like anything derivable in S+ should also be derivable in S. After all, S+ has no new rules and no new formulas compared to S. But on the other hand, isn't it possible to make very specific restrictions when creating the language L+ that can be used in conjunction with the rules of the system to yield theorems S does not have?
Let us define a language L+ whose primitive symbols are:

p, q, r... [propositional variables]
¬          [monadic operator]
→, G       [dyadic operator]
(, )       [brackets]

The formation rules of L+ are the following:

FR1: A propositional variable is a wff
FR2: If A is a wff, then so is ¬A
FR3: If A and B are wffs, then so is A→B
FR4: If A and B are wffs of the language of propositional logic, and there is a model of propositional logic in which A is true (herefrom will refer to this as "logically consistent"), then G(A,B) is a wff.

Note how G(A,B) can only be the main connective. Let us now define a language L so that it has the same set of primitive symbols as L+. The formation rules of L are:

FR1: A propositional variable is a wff
FR2: If A is a wff, then so is ¬A
FR3: If A and B are wffs, then so is A→B
FR4: If A and B are wffs of the language of propositional logic, then G(A,B) is a wff.

Since every formula of L+ is a formula of L, L+ is a sublanguage of L. Let us take this axiom schema:

If A is a tautology, then A is an axiom.

And two inference rules:

If A and A→B are theorems, so is B
If A→B is a tautology, and A is logically consistent, then G(A,B) is a theorem.

Now let us create two systems:

S+ is specified by the language L+, the axiom schema above and the two inference rules given above.
S is specified by the language L, the axiom schema above and the two inference rules given above.

We note that all axioms and inference rules of S and S+ are the same, and that L+ is a sublanguage of L, so the systems defined are precisely the ones relevant to this question.
Let us reason within S+. Assume some L+ formula G(A,B). Since G(A,B) is a formula of L+, and the language of L+ only allows for formulas in which A is logically consistent, then A is logically consistent by the assumption. We can use inference rule 2 to derive G(A, B→B). Therefore, in S+, G(A, B→B) is derivable from G(A,B).
Let us reason within S. Assume some L formula G(A,B). Since G(A,B) is a formula of L, A does not have to be logically consistent. It could be an inconsistent formula as well. So we can not use inference rule 2 as in the previous scenario to conclude that G(A, B→B) is derivable from G(A,B). And since there are no other rules by which G-formulas can be derived, the conclusion that G(A, B→B) is derivable from G(A,B) simply does not necessarily follow in S.
Therefore, even though L+ is a sublanguage of L, and S+ and S have he same axioms/inference rules, it is not the case that if A and B are wffs of L+, if A |- B in S+, then A |- B in S.

Please use MathJax for the formulas in your MSE posts. It makes even simple things like $L_+$ (or should that be $L^+$) and ${A}$ much easier to read. As for the question, in the usual understanding of a system of axioms and inference rules, the side-conditions on each inference rule only refer to the formulas that appear in an instance of the rule and not to global properties of the language, so the answer to the question in your title (which should also be stated in the body) is yes.

@RobArthan but are the theorems of S+ directly available in S, or is some sort of specification needed? I.e if T is a theorem in S+ that was obtained specifically by using that special property of L+ formulas, can you really claim that same formula is derivable in S in a non conditional form?

The proof of a theorem in $S_+$ is also a valid proof in $S$. What kind of properties of $L_+$ formulas do you have in mind? If there are $L_+$ formulas that aren't in $L$, then $L_+$ isn't a sublanguage of $L$.

Let's define L+ to be an extension of the language of propositional logic with one addition, G(a,b) is a formula of L+ iff a and b are formulas of propositional logic and a is logically consistent. Let's take it that one of the rules in {A} is that when a logically entails b and a is consistent, then G(a,b) is derivable from the empty set. Now let L be the same as L+ but G(a,b) is a formula even if a is not consistent.

@RobArthan So there's a bunch of derivations related to G(a,b) that are provable within S+, but they all rely on the fact that the formula that we are assuming has the first parameter consistent. I.e the proof of G(a,b) |- G(c,d) starts with the assumption of G(a,b), and since in L+ we know that a is consistent, one of the rules eventually helps us reach G(c,d). But is it truly the case that in L we can just say G(a,b) |- G(c,d)?

What do you mean by "in $L_+$, $a$ is consistent"? You need to come up with a much more specific example of the problem you have in mind.

@RobArthan You are reasoning within S+, and you assume G(a,b). Therefore, a is a logically consistent formula, because G(a,b) is only a wff of L+ if a is consistent. You use the fact that a is consistent in conjunction with some of the inference rules or axioms to derive some other formulas. Let that other formula be G(c,d). So that ultimately G(a,b) |- G(c,d) in S+. Is G(a,b) |- G(c,d) in S as well?

Here's a simpler example. Let's say that L is the language of propositional logic whose primitive connectives are ~ and ->. Let L+ be the language you get by requiring that a->b can be a formula of L+ iff a and b are formulas of L, and a is logically consistent. In S+ you can probably prove that "if a->b is derivable from the empty set, then b is consistent" since you know a will be consistent. But this is not provable in propositional logic itself. So we have same axioms/rules, L+ is a sub language of L, and yet this is not a theorem of propositional logic.

What do you mean by "logically consistent"?

Formula A of propositional logic is semantically consistent iff there is an interpretation under which A is true

So how does restricting to consistent formulas in that sense extend the range of provable formulas?

@RobArthan I have given you two examples of how it does so. Read through them please, and explain what you want clarified.

The onus is on you to explain your concerns.

@RobArthan I just fear that you aren't participating in the discussion in good faith, because I have explained them. Define L+ to be an extension of the language of propositional logic with one addition, G(a,b) is a formula of L+ iff a and b are formulas of propositional logic and a is a semantically consistent formula of propositional logic. Let's take it that one of the rules in {A} is that when a logically entails b and a is consistent, then G(a,b) is derivable from the empty set. Now let L be the same as L+ but G(a,b) is a formula even if a is not consistent.

Within S+, G(a,b) |- G(a, c v ~c). This proof is simple. Assume G(a,b). The language of L+ only has G(a,b) in which a is a semantically consistent formula of propositional logic. Therefore, since a is consistent and a entails c v ~c, G(a, c v ~c) is derivable by the rule we introduced previously. In S+, G(a,b) |- G(a, c v ~c). In S, this is simply not necessarily the case. The assumption of G(a,b) does not yield that a is consistent because the language of L has formulas G(x,y) in which x is not consistent. Therefore you can't use the rule as in the previous scenario.

So in S+, G(a,b) |- G(a, c v ~c). In G(a, c v ~c) is not necessarily derivable from G(a,b).

As you don't think I am participating in good faith, I will not participate in any further discussion on this question.

That's okay. You did help me articulate the question a lot better, so thanks for that at least.

The problem with your counterexample is in two parts, depending on whether or not the particular wff A is consistent.
Case 1: A is consistent. Then your deduction of G(A,B$\to$B) from G(A,B) in S+ also works in S, so this case doesn't produce a counterexample.
Case 2: A is inconsistent. Then, as you wrote, G(A,B$\to$B) is not deducible from G(A,B) in S. But it's not deducible in S+ either, for the trivial reason that neither G(A,B$\to$B) nor G(A,B) is even a wff in S+.
So neither case actually gives a counterexample.
Your counterexample shows that, if we know the general fact "for every wff G(A,B) of S+ we can deduce G(A,B$\to$B) from G(A,B) in S+," it doesn't follow that the same general fact holds when you change S+ to S. But that shouldn't be a surprise since the meaning of "for every wff" gets stronger when you move from S+ to S. And as soon as you look at specific wffs, say X and Y, rather than a general claim about "every wff", it is true that if X is deducible  from Y in S+ then it's also deducible in S.

Thank you. I find this part quite interesting "for the trivial reason that neither G(A,B→
B) nor G(A,B) is even a wff in S+".
The question below is loosely connected to my original one, but I would be extremely grateful if you could answer it.  What if rule 3 was added to the inference rules that stated "If A is logically inconsistent, then G(A,B) is a theorem." Let A be inconsistent. Would it still be true that "G(A,B→B) is not deducible from G(A,B)" in S+ for the trivial reason that neither of these are L+ formulas?

This is not intended as a direct answer to the question, but could provide some pointers for the discussion.
A language $\mathcal{L}$ is a sublanguage of language $\mathcal{L'}$, denoted by $\mathcal{L}\subseteq\mathcal{L'}$, iff $\mathcal{L'}$ is obtained from $\mathcal{L}$ by the addition of new non-logical symbols.
Suppose we have two such languages, $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{L'}$, together with an $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathfrak{A}$ and an $\mathcal{L'}$-structure $\mathfrak{A'}$. Then, we can say the following about them:
$\mathfrak{A}$ is the reduct of $\mathfrak{A'}$ to $\mathcal{L}$, and $\mathfrak{A'}$ is an expansion of $\mathfrak{A}$ to $\mathcal{L'}$ iff

$\Vert\mathfrak{A}\Vert =\Vert\mathfrak{A'}\Vert$ (where $\Vert.\Vert$ denoting the cardinality of the universe),

For every constant symbol $c\in\mathcal{L}, c^{\mathfrak{A}} = c^{\mathfrak{A'}}$,

For every function symbol $f\in\mathcal{L}, f^{\mathfrak{A}} = f^{\mathfrak{A'}}$,

For every predicate symbol $P\in\mathcal{L}, P^{\mathfrak{A}} = P^{\mathfrak{A'}}$.


If an $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathfrak{A}$ is a reduct of an $\mathcal{L'}$-structure $\mathfrak{A'}$, then for all $\mathcal{L}$-sentences
$$\mathfrak{A}\vDash\phi\iff\mathfrak{A'}\vDash\phi$$
A theory $T$ is a collection of sentences (propositions) closed with respect to derivability:
$$T\vdash\phi\implies\phi\in T$$
We can specify an axiom set $\Gamma$ (i.e., the elements of which are axioms) of the theory $T$ such that
$$T =\{\phi\;\vert\;\Gamma\vdash\phi\}$$
Thus, we may talk about $Th(\mathcal{L})$, the set of all theories of $\mathcal{L}$, and $Th_{\mathcal{L}}(\Gamma)$, the theory generated in $Th(\mathcal{L})$ by $\Gamma$.
Let $T$ and $T'$ be theories in the languages $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{L'}$.

$T'$ is an extension of $T$ if $T\subseteq T'$
$T'$ is a conservative extension of $T$ if $T'\cap\mathcal{L}=T$

We have reviewed the basic notions relevant to the question. It can be seen that those notions unfold through a common principle, usually called monotonicity of entailment:
$$\Gamma\vdash\phi\text{ and }\Gamma\subset\Gamma'\implies\Gamma'\vdash\phi$$
This principle, adopted in classical as well as intuitionistic logic, rules out such possibilities as described in the question. Therefore, if a case could be made for them, it must be sought in non-monotonic systems.

Thank you for taking the time to answer! Do you think my example with G(a,b) in the question is a valid counter example?

Perhaps you have in mind sort of a computer program that would handle an exceptional state by a few tweaks. Anyhow, I advise you to write down your argument line by line annotating them with the definitions and rules from a textbook (I recommend Open Logic Project's and Leary and Kristiansen's A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic). What you are after may not be the one expressed in the question. If so, you can check the argument as a separate question.

I have edited my question a bit more to make the argument line by line. Is this better?

That's better. So, you can see you have defined A such that it amounts to verum, $\top$, then revoked that, etc.  One improves rigour studying the arguments/derivations in the textbooks (later, those of the masters). If you use more symbols, your expressions will get clearer and more precise.  A quick way to learn MathJax is to click the "edit" button in the answers and look up the code.
